# How does a skipping rope know how many nodes I want?

Tags: waves, vibrations

Say I have a skipping rope. I have fixed it in one end and I'm holding it in the other. When I start spinning it, I know that I can make it spin in one large arc, or in two smaller arcs with a stationary node in the middle, or in three arcs with two equally spaced nodes, and so on.

How exactly do I do that? Especially if there's no gravity, I see no reason that the node of spinning is directly tied to the rotational frequency, or to the distance between my hand and the anchor point (the total "slack length" of the rope). At least once it has stabilized. So what is it that I do with my hand that tells the rope which mode to use?

Comment: How do you walk upright? The feedback loops in your various control systems work without much (if any) conscious input.

Comment: @JonCuster More concretely, then: If I took my end of the rope, and tied it to a wheel, rotational axis pointing to the other anchor point, and wanted to program an engine attached to the wheel to make the rope rotate at a certain velocity with a certain number of nodes, starting from rest in gravity, or very, very slow first mode spin in no gravity, how would I program it?

Comment: Is that even possible? I would love to see a video of a spinning skiprope with a node in the middle.

Comment: @BillN They do it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-k2TuJfNQ9s) with a slinky waving up and down. So it's not the same phenomenon. But seen from the side, when you don't have depth perception, it's basically what it looks like. And it is definitely possible. I did it myself just this weekend, with two nodes, which is what made me wonder.

Comment: @Arthur No, that's not a spinning system. It's only vibrating (mainly) in a single plane. It do this demonstration several times a year with both springs and ropes, but they are vibrating transversely, not spinning.  Is your question about these transverse waves? You use the word "spin."

Comment: @BillN I know. I'll repeat: So it's not the same phenomenon. But seen from the side, when you don't have depth perception, it's basically what it looks like.

Comment: Here is an example on YouTube. https://youtu.be/H7qr8VvE3Cw

Answer (score 0):

It is based on the initial conditions of the system.

The one large arc mode is the naturally stable configuration because the potential energy of the rope with respect to the rotating reference frame (centripetal force) is at its absolute minimum.

Two arcs with a stationary node is most easily archived by two rope operators. First the rope is put into one arc mode, then one of the operators quickly changes rotational phase by 180degrees. In this fashion one operators hand is now up while the other is down. This accelerates that side of the rope creating the two arc mode.

Two arcs is similarly achievable by a single rope operator by first establishing kinetic energy near the fixed end of the rope in single arc mode, then quickly changing phase 180 degrees to accelerate the operator side of the loop ahead of the fixed end.

The two arc mode is locally stable because the potential energy of the rope with respect to the rotating reference frame is at a **local** minimum.

This procedure can be repeated for additional arcs/nodes of ever decreasing stability. At some point system noise (rope linear density, air friction, movement consistency, etc) and operator timing ability limit how many nodes can be created.